# When should we use std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, enable-shared-from-this

I just knew `std::enable_shared_from_this` form [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).
But after reading the code below, I don't know when to use it.

```
try {
        Good not_so_good;
        std::shared_ptr<Good> gp1 = not_so_good.getptr();
    } catch(std::bad_weak_ptr& e) {
        // undefined behavior (until C++17) and std::bad_weak_ptr thrown (since C++17)
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';    
    }
```

The code above is "not so good" because there is no existing `shared_ptr` before calling `getptr()`. So the good thing should be:

```
std::shared_ptr<Good> gp1 = std::make_shared<Good>(); // having a shared_ptr at the beginning
std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1->getptr();
```

However, if I have already had a `shared_ptr` object, why don't I just simply code like this: `std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1;`, meaning that I don't need `std::enable_shared_from_this` at all.

In my opinion, using `std::enable_shared_from_this` is to make sure that more than one `shared_ptr` objects have the same control block so that we can avoid [the double-delete problem](https://ideone.com/FlvIWw). But if I must remind myself to create a `shared_ptr` at the beginning, why don't I just remind myself to use `shared_ptr` object to create a new one, instead of using raw pointer?

Comment: `void f(Good& g); /* ... */ f(*gp1); /* ... */ void f(Good& g) { /* now what? */ }`

Comment: @milleniumbug  sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: The `f` doesn't have the access to the `shared_ptr`, as it takes a reference, not a shared pointer. Sometimes you could change so it takes a reference instead, but not for member functions - `this` is always a raw pointer.

Comment: @milleniumbug  I think you misunderstand my question. My question is: using `std::enable_shared_from_this` doesn't save us from the risk of double delete. If so, `std::enable_shared_from_this` is useless. See the example: https://ideone.com/FlvIWw

Comment: Well you're wrong. `std::enable_shared_from_this` isn't supposed to be a protection from misusing the `shared_ptr`'s interface. For a use case of it, see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hint about when `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` is useful is in its name: when yielding objects based on some requests it may be necessary to return a pointer to an object itself. If the result should be a `std::shared_ptr<T>` it becomes necessary to return such a pointer from within a member function where there is generally no `std::shared_ptr<T>` accessible.

Having derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` provides a way to get hold of a `std::shared_ptr<T>` given just a pointer of type `T`. Doing so does, however, assume that the object is already managed via a `std::shared_ptr<T>` and it would create mayhem if the object is allocated on the stack:

```
struct S: std::enable_shared_from_this<S> {
    std::shared_ptr<S> get_object() {
        return this->shared_from_this();
    };
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<S> ptr1 = std::make_shared<S>();
    std::shared_ptr<S> ptr2 = ptr1->get_object();
    // ...
}
```

In a realistic scenario there is probably some condition under which a `std::shared_ptr<T>` to the current object is returned.

Answer (score 3):

There're some use case which you can't use the template `std::shared_ptr<T>` like opaque pointer.

In that case, it's useful to have this:

In some_file.cpp

```
struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {};

extern "C" void f_c(A*);
extern "C" void f_cpp(A* a) {
   std::shared_ptr<A> shared_a = a->shared_from_this();
   // work with operation requires shared_ptr
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    f_c(a.get());
}
```

---

In some_other.c

```
struct A;
void f_cpp(struct A* a);
void f_c(struct A* a) {
    f_cpp(a);
}
```

Comment: i am kind of confused, why should i use sharea_ptr for a in f_cpp? if f_cpp required that, it should accept a shared_ptr instead of raw pointef A*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I want to represent a computation tree. We'll have an addition represented as a class deriving from expression with two pointers to expressions, so an expression can be evaluated recursively. However, we need to end the evaluation somewhere, so let's have numbers evaluate to themselves.

```
class Number;

class Expression : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Expression>
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Number> evaluate() = 0;
    virtual ~Expression() {}
};

class Number : public Expression
{
    int x;
public:
    int value() const { return x; }
    std::shared_ptr<Number> evaluate() override
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Number>(shared_from_this());
    }
    Number(int x) : x(x) {}
};

class Addition : public Expression
{
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> right;
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Number> evaluate() override
    {
        int l = left->evaluate()->value();
        int r = right->evaluate()->value();
        return std::make_shared<Number>(l + r);
    }
    Addition(std::shared_ptr<Expression> left, std::shared_ptr<Expression> right) :
        left(left),
        right(right)
    {

    }
};
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09953bdb54e6c3a)</kbd>

Note that the "obvious" way of implementing `Number::evaluate()` with `return std::shared_ptr<Number>(this);` is broken because it will result in double delete.

Comment: The return type of `evaluate` should be `std::shared_ptr<Number>`, saving you from all the evil casting.

Comment: You forgot to specify the base class of `Number` and `Addition`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, in this sample code one simply do that. My program had different types which is why I initially didn't do that. (it's also sad that I have to use a cast from `std::shared_from_this()` but I guess such is life)

Comment: @Oktalist Fixed. Also added a link to coliru.

Comment: You have to explicitly cast `shared_ptr<Expression>` to `shared_ptr<Number>` for the same reason that you'd have to explicitly cast `Expression*` to `Number*` if you were using raw pointers. It's only unfortunate if the return type of `Expression::evaluate` is `shared_ptr<Expression>` (which seems reasonable) that `shared_ptr<Number>` wouldn't qualify as a covariant return type.

Comment: I'd be *very* tempted to make all of `Expression`'s and `Number`s constructors `protected`, and provide factories

Comment: I'd be very tempted not to use `shared_ptr` at all here. Use `unique_ptr`s, or pass by value - the code is simpler and double deletion isn't an issue.